# Shortcut to enable / disable VoIP/SIP on Gingerbread?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, voip, sip

Gingerbread comes with a cool SIP / VoIP integration. However, this feature drains the battery quite a bit.

So I'm looking for a shortcut to enable SIP. So far, I always have to go deep into Settings to disable/enable it.

Is there a cool shortcut, widget or app which helps to enable/disable the native SIP/VoIP-Feature of Android 2.3?

Comment: From where you have got in-built SIP client?

Comment: It's part of Android, IIRC since 2.3.

Comment: No...it's not. Either you're using custom ROM or it's OEM's work..

Comment: It is. I've got stock ROMs in HTC Desire S and Samsung Galaxy Nexus S, and both have SIP functionality. See also here: http://www.voipvoip.com/android/sip.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I did not find any suitable solutions I decided to write my own widget.

It's available on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.siebeck.sipswitch

I also made the source code available: https://github.com/robert7k/sipswitch